# how to cast a loaded class into an interface class in Android

Tags: java, android, plugins, interface, casting

i have two projects, let's say projectMain and projectPlugin.
i have an interface class.

this is the interface class code :

```
package com.far.lib;

public interface IPlugin {

    public String getNamaModul();
    public String getNamaPaket();
}
```

and i use projectMain as a library project for the projectPlugin.
and i make a class that implements the interface class from projectMain, here is the code :

```
package com.example.helloworld.plugin;

public class PluginHelloWorld implements com.far.lib.IPlugin{

    @Override
    public String getNamaModul() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "Modul Hello World";
    }

    @Override
    public String getNamaPaket() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "com.example.helloworld";
    }

}
```

then i compile projectPlugin to get an apk file, and i change the apk file to a jar file, and i add a manifest file in it, here is the manifest code :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Module-Class: com.example.helloworld.plugin.PluginHelloWorld <-- this line of code is the code that i added in the manifest file
```

and then i have a class that read from a jar file to load jar files. Here is the code :

```
public class PluginManager {

public static List<PluginModel> getPlugins(Activity activty) {
    List<PluginModel> plugins = new ArrayList<PluginModel>();
    File pluginLoc = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/Plugin/");

    File[] pluginList = pluginLoc.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File pathname) {
            Log.d("file path", pathname.toString());
            return pathname.getPath().toLowerCase().endsWith(".jar");
        }
    });
    // URL[] urls = new URL[pluginList.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < pluginList.length; i++) {
            JarFile jarFile = null;
            try {
                jarFile = new JarFile(pluginList[i]);
                Manifest manifest = jarFile.getManifest();
                String ModuleClassName = manifest.getMainAttributes().getValue(
                        "Module-Class");
                Log.d("test", ModuleClassName);
                File DexOutputFile = activty.getDir("outdex",
                        Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                DexClassLoader dcl = new DexClassLoader(
                        pluginList[i].getAbsolutePath(),
                        DexOutputFile.getAbsolutePath(), null,
                        ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
                Class<?> clazz = dcl.loadClass(ModuleClassName);
                // Log.d("test", clazz.getClassLoader().toString());
                // Log.d("test1",IPlugin.class.getClassLoader().toString());
                IPlugin temp = (IPlugin) clazz.newInstance();
                plugins.add(new PluginModel(namaModul, namaPaket));
            } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
       return plugins;
    }
}
```

i get ClassCastException Error as shown at the image below :

> 03-20 20:53:30.453: W/System.err(15986): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.helloworld.plugin.PluginHelloWorld cannot be cast to com.far.lib.IPlugin
>   03-20 20:53:30.453: W/System.err(15986):    at com.far.plugin.PluginManager.getPlugins(PluginManager.java:61)
>   03-20 20:53:30.453: W/System.err(15986):    at com.far.exampleplugin2.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:32)
>   03-20 20:53:30.453: W/System.err(15986):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1192)
>   03-20 20:53:30.453: W/System.err(15986):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5211)
>   03-20 20:53:30.453: W/System.err(15986):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2780)
>   03-20 20:53:30.453: W/System.err(15986):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2819)
>   03-20 20:53:30.453: W/System.err(15986):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2266)
>   03-20 20:53:30.453: W/System.err(15986):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
>   03-20 20:53:30.453: W/System.err(15986):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
>   03-20 20:53:30.453: W/System.err(15986):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   03-20 20:53:30.453: W/System.err(15986):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   03-20 20:53:30.453: W/System.err(15986):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
>   03-20 20:53:30.453: W/System.err(15986):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   03-20 20:53:30.453: W/System.err(15986):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>   03-20 20:53:30.453: W/System.err(15986):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
>   03-20 20:53:30.453: W/System.err(15986):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>   03-20 20:53:30.453: W/System.err(15986):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

i used Log to print each classloader from clazz and IPlugin, and the result is different. this is the result :

> 03-20 20:56:09.253: D/test(16698): dalvik.system.DexClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/storage/emulated/0/Plugin/HelloWorld1.jar"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib]]]
>   03-20 20:56:09.253: D/test1(16698): dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.far.exampleplugin2-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.far.exampleplugin2-1, /system/lib]]]

the thing that i'm asking here is how to cast a loaded class into an interface class from projectMain ?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

ClassCastExceptions on compatible classes in java happen if the class loading is not compatible. This might happen if your application is not loaded by the system class loader. As I'm not a android expert I'm not sure whether the locked class loader is the system class loader or not. So you might configure the DexClassLoader with the class loader of the class that's executed at the moment `this.getClass().getClassLoader()` or the one of the interface you want to be compatible with `IPlugin.class.getClassLoader()` as the parent class loader. Those are the class loaders you need to be compatible with. `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` might be worth a try, too.

```
            DexClassLoader dcl = new DexClassLoader(
                    pluginList[i].getAbsolutePath(),
                    DexOutputFile.getAbsolutePath(), null,
                    IPlugin.class.getClassLoader());
```

Comment: i found new warning & errors when using your answer. warning: `03-21 09:58:11.524: W/dalvikvm(2326): Class resolved by unexpected DEX: Lcom/example/helloworld/plugin/PluginHelloWorld;(0xa5465b30):0x97ee3000 ref [Lcom/far/lib/IPlugin;] Lcom/far/lib/IPlugin;(0xa543e0a8):0x98015000 03-21 09:58:11.524: W/dalvikvm(2326): (Lcom/example/helloworld/plugin/PluginHelloWorld; had used a different Lcom/far/lib/IPlugin; during pre-verification)`

error:
`03-21 09:52:57.308: E/AndroidRuntime(2147): java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation`